# i can not register an user by using create_user() method in django

Tags: python, django

This my app's code.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
        last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
        email = request.POST['email'],
        username = request.POST['username'],
        password = request.POST['password'],
        password2 = request.POST['password2'],


        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    return redirect('register')
                else:
                    print(username,email,password,first_name,last_name)

                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email,
                                                first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                    print(username, email, password, first_name, last_name)
                    user.save()
                    return redirect('login')
        else:
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(request,'blog/register.html')
```

There print() function is executed. but user = User.objects.create_user() is not working. 
i do not understand why it is not working.
[ I don't understand the problem.( browser show:)[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBbjo.png)

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cejRD.png)

Comment: just print error below, image has bad cropping

Comment: hi Ismaili, just learn about django forms and how to access [`cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added commas at the end of the definitions of first_name, last_name etc. This turns them into tuples. Remove those commas.

But as Dani points out in the comments, you should be using forms. Especially as there is a UserCreationForm already built in to Django.